# why bootstrap modal is not working

Tags: database, loops, modal-dialog, echo

I have created forms to allow me to select member button than retrieve information from the database into the table and update it after made change is working great.

Now I want to move that forms into the BOOTSTRAP MODAL but is not working, when I click the button just slides down bootstrap model AND then DISAPPEAR right away.

What did I miss it…

```
<form method='post'>

<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['id_boxe'] . "'/>

<input type='submit' name='update' value='Update' href='#modal-view' role='button' class='btn' data-toggle='modal''/>

</form>

</td>
```

Retrieve information from database after click button.. (outside modal)

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
       $id = trim($_POST['id']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM boxes where id_boxe = " . $id;
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $title = $row['title_boxe'];
                $status = $row['status'];
                $side = $row['side'];

            }
            $result->close();
        }
        ?>
```

Section bootstrap modal: (echo information inside modal)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-view" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">

                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                ×
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                Modal title
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form method="post" class="col-md-6">
            <?php if(isset($id)) {?>
            <input type="hidden" name="id_boxe" value="<?=$id?>"/>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="boxe_title">Boxe Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="boxe_title" value="<?php if(isset($title)) echo $title; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <select name="side">
                <?php if(isset($side) && $side == 1) {  ?>
                    <option value="1" selected>right</option>
                <?php } else {?>
                     <option value="1">right</option>
                <?php } ?>

                     <?php if(isset($side) && $side == 2) {  ?>
                    <option value="2" selected>left</op)tion>
                <?php } else {?>
                     <option value="2">left</option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="select">
                <?php if(isset($status) && $status == 1) {  ?>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="visibility" checked> Visible in the Menu</label>
                <?php } else {?>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="visibility" > Visible in the Menu</label>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php if (isset($_POST['id'])) { ?>
                <button type="submit"  name="updatedata" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <button type="submit"  name="add" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                Close
                            </button> 
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Save changes
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

My question is that what did I missed to show bootstrap modal with profile information instead of disappear bootstrap modal!

Is works fine before bootstrap modal but after moved that forms to bootstrap modal is not working..

What I missed!
Thank you for your help…
AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the form with the submit button is causing the problem, perhaps it is showing the modal quickly because of the `data-toggle` on the submit button but then since you are triggering a form submit it reloads the page causing the modal to disappear.

Try changing your button to: 
    `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-view">Launch demo modal</button>`

[Like it shows in the demo on bootstrap's site.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Also you might want to read up on [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) because your code looks vulnerable.

It is hard to tell what the problem is with the modal without seeing a full HTML output, can you provide that in jsfiddle?

Comment: thank you so much, i tried that button <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-view">Launch demo modal</button> at this time is not disappear, is slide down and disable, is not allow met to make change on modal. what wrong with that!

Comment: I'm not sure, can you do a "view source" on the page and then paste the HTML to jsfiddle.net? That will make it much easier to debug.

Comment: here is link for jsfiddle, i tried evrything i could ... https://jsfiddle.net/2kLkv3qf/

Comment: Unfortunately this has php code in it so it isn't going to work here. If you view your page in the browser, then right click and select `view source` then copy and paste all of that code into JSFiddle it should load correctly. Alternatively if you just give us the link to your development page we could go look at it there.

Comment: yes i updated again please see https://jsfiddle.net/2kLkv3qf/ .. one thing, before i put bootstrap i use button code like this 
<input type='submit' name='update' value='Update'/> that allow me to see information from database and upate, but then combined with bootstrap modal and button is showing modal but no retereive information from database. is blank. see jsfiddle please.

Comment: Ok, I made a few changes I think might fix it: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpk1o7a7/1/

I added a link for `Update` which changes the ID, then updated the SQL statement to use $_REQUEST so it can get either post or get requests. Also I wrapped it in `intval()` which will cast it to a integer. I would still rewrite this to prevent SQL Injection though.